# Macro Plug in

Tags: excel, vba

Currently this macro is set up so that if Column G has “Last Term” and “Okay” or “Okay” and “Stay” next to each other 07a will be entered into the same row in Column I.   I would like to modify this code so that If Column G contains “Last Term” and Column K contains “Okay” and “End” or “Okay” and “Stay” in any combination or in any order, possibly with other words in between, before, or behind them as long as these two different combinations are present then 07a will be entered into Column I in the same row.

Sub Plugin()
    Dim nRow    As Long
    Dim iRow    As Long

```
nRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For iRow = 1 To nRow
    With Cells(iRow, "G")
        If .Text Like "Okay*" Or .Text Like "End*" Then
            Cells(iRow, "I") = "07a"
        If .Text Like "Okay*" Or .Text Like "Stay*" Then
            Cells(iRow, "I") = "07a"
        End If
    End With
Next iRow
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
Sub Plugin()
Dim nRow As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim KUpperText As String

nRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For iRow = 1 To nRow
    KUpperText = UCase(Cells(iRow, "K").Text)
    If UCase(Cells(iRow, "G").Text) Like UCase("Last Term*") Then
        If ((KUpperText Like "*END*" And KUpperText Like "*OKAY*") _
         Or (KUpperText Like "*STAY*" And KUpperText Like "*OKAY*")) Then
            Cells(iRow, "I") = "07a"
        End If
    End If
Next iRow
End Sub
```

For each loop, I read the Text string in column K.
It is formatted in upper case to be sure that both "End" and "END" are handled for example.

Comment: When using the With statement, there's no problem with testing or setting the attributes of the referenced object. That's pretty much the purpose of the With statement

Comment: @barrowc You are absolutely right. I've tested adding the "With" and it also works.  I've edited my answer to remove the incorrect statement.